# Trying to install custom root CA made firefox unusable

Tags: firefox, certificates

After trying to add a new root CA by placing it to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/extra/` and doing `sudo update-ca-certificates`, Firefox cannot load **any** webpage.

[image: Firfefox not loading any webpage]

Chrome works fine.

After removing the extra certs and doing `apt install --reinstall ca-certificates` or doing `sudo update-ca-certificates` the problem still persists.

Removing cert?.db-s in Firefox or deleting `~/.cache/mozilla/` does not help. Installing a fresh firefox-nightly also does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem was icaclient itself. Just turn off app protection, ie. reinstall without app protection support.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66337540/firefox-shows-only-blank-pages-even-aboutconfig-is-just-white